# Python individual digit extraction regex issue

Tags: python, regex

Why is my code extracting individual digits in a number instead of the number (i.e. "300" is extracted as 3, then 0, then another 0)?

```
import re
open_file = open("regex_sum_42.txt")
read_file = open_file.read()
for line in read_file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    num_list = re.findall(".*([0-9])+",line)
    if len(num_list)>0:
        print num_list
```

Comment: There are three problems with your code: 1) The `+` needs to go _inside_ the group like so: `([0-9]+)`, otherwise the group only captures a single digit. 2) The `.*` in front of the capture group will consume all digits but the last one. You need to make this non-greedy: `.*?([0-9]+)`. 3) You're iterating through the text character by character, not line by line.

Comment: This was my final code: import re
full_num_list = []
open_file = open("regex_sum_245272.txt")
read_file = open_file.read()
print sum(map(int,re.findall("([0-9]+)",read_file)))

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
re.findall(r"\d+", line)
```

Comment: Not only. That is not enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok now?

Comment: Now, it makes the question a dupe :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Haha..good one :)